# Change of Variable Question...

Tags: calculus, integration, change-of-variable

I'm trying to use the "change of variable" technique to integrate this function.

I have this function

$I_1 = \int_0^{\infty} \frac{\alpha  \mu  x (1+\mu  x)^{-\alpha -1}}{1-\lambda x  (1+\mu  x)^{-\alpha }}dx$

To integrate this, one way is to use the change of variable technique. I see that

$u = (1 +\mu x)^{-\alpha }$

and

$du = -\alpha  \mu  (\mu  x+1)^{-\alpha -1}  dx$

so now,

$I_2 = -\int \frac{x du}{1-\lambda x u}$.

But, there is still an "extra" $x$.

Is it possible to do "change of variables" twice?

How can this be done?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the fact that
$$x=\frac{1}{\mu}(u^{-\frac{1}{\alpha}}-1)$$

Hope this helps.